# Video game melding FPS with miniature golf in a tale of either ghosts or zombies

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Several years ago (I honestly don't remember when, although it must have been at least 5 years ago, probably more), I received a [Desura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desura) key for a game. It was a meld of minigolf and an FPS with the framing narrative involving you being a worker (owner?) of a minigolf facility on the coast where an invasion of pirate zombies or ghosts was happening. I remember the first bit of the game had you doing a minigolf challenge on the courses, whereupon you were set upon by your first undead. As I recall it, there was a general shooting function where you just kind of fired at a point with a golf ball (I think the conceit might have involved a pneumatic tube delivery?) and then the other "weapon" choices were various golf clubs that gave you a way to set the power and angle of the shot. I never made it past the first level or so, and in 2015, Desura collapsed, which means I no longer have access to that game.

I've done a few searches for related terms, but haven't found anything. Some part of me wants to make it Nordic... maybe Vikings instead of pirates? But there was definitely an FPS setup with golf as part of the weapons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*The Curse of Nordic Cove*](http://hellnotes.com/the-curse-of-nordic-cove-game-combines-survival-horror-and-golf-well-why-not/)

> The Curse of Nordic Cove is a proudly brutal indie game that combines first-person shooting with survival horror, golf, driving and adventure to create something quite bizarre. Developed by On The Level Game Studios, the game is available now for Windows, Mac and Linux, and for a limited time is just £3.25 / $4.99 via Amazon and Desura.

Comment: Thank you. Just could not figure out the right search keywords last night...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It happens that I had this one. All I needed to do was remember the name.